# How to wire new switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I'm trying to insert a motion switch and am not positive on the connections I need to make. I'm trying to **replace SWITCH A**. Switch A was previously part of a simple 3-way setup, but now is just a dumb switch directly to the light. The way the red line is used is definitely giving me pause. Please see the specs below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 blacks From the switch go to the red and orange.

Doesn’t matter clip the reds straighten and use a wire nut to combine the 3 wires. Then black to orange with a wire nut.
The white on the switch goes to that group of whites
If you have a white on the switch, last the green to the ground or bare copper.

That it was a 3 way doesn’t matter if the other switch was removed and you have an always hot.